# Selenium WebDriverWait doesn't wait elementToBeClickable

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a test where for loop click on each submenu items, but webdriver doesn't wait element and throws exception and tries to click next submenu item and so on.

Here is ElementFetch class:

```
public class ElementFetch {
    
    public Actions action;
    
    private WebDriver driver;
    private WebDriverWait wait;
    
    public ElementFetch(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.wait = wait;
        this.action = new Actions(driver);
    }
    
    public void click(By locator) {
        try {
            WebElement element = wait.withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
            action.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error clicking the element: " + locator);
        }
    }...
```

Here is BaseTest class that my tests extend:

```
public class BaseTest {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public WebDriverWait wait;
    public Properties testConfig;
    public ElementFetch elementFetch;
    public Authentication authentication;
    public ModalChecker modalChecker;
    
    
    private final String configPath = "src\\test\\resources\\config\\config.properties";
    
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        driver = DriverManager.initializeDriver();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
        testConfig = ConfigurationLoader.loadTestConfig(configPath);
        
        elementFetch = new ElementFetch(driver, wait);
```

Here is subMenu test that fails in MenuTest class:

```
public class MenuTest extends BaseTest {
    
    private String path = "";
    
    @Test(dataProvider = "dataProviderMainMenu", dataProviderClass = DataProviderClass.class)
    public void testMainMenu(JsonObject menuItem) throws InterruptedException {

        elementFetch.click(By.id(menuItem.get("id").getAsString().replace("\"", "")));
        
        if (menuItem.has("subMenu")) {
            JsonArray subMenuItems = menuItem.getAsJsonArray("subMenu");
            testSubMenu(subMenuItems);
        }
    }
    
    public void testSubMenu(JsonArray subMenuItems) throws InterruptedException {
        for(JsonElement subMenuItem : subMenuItems) {
            JsonObject subMenuItemObject = subMenuItem.getAsJsonObject();

            elementFetch.click(By.id(subMenuItemObject.get("id").getAsString()));
            wait.until(driver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
            
            if (subMenuItemObject.has("menu")) {
                JsonArray submenu = subMenuItemObject.get("menu").getAsJsonArray();
                String originalPath = path;
                testSubMenu(submenu);
                path = originalPath;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm expecting webdriver to wait for element to be clickable and click it, but it doesn't wait and looks for another button

Comment: You can't be sure that this is the issue because you are masking the error message. Remove the `try catch` or at least print the actual error message.

Comment: labas :)  whats the actual exception?

Comment: I think you want: WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)); and then just use element.click(); method.

Comment: in your catch use System.err.println("Error clicking the element: "+ e.toString();); So you can include the exception in your post.